# Access Control that are used on Ubuntu?

Tags: access-control

I want to ask about access control that are used on Ubuntu. I already read Ubuntu Access Control List but I'm still confused. Is there someone can explain about access control on Ubuntu? Because honestly, I don't really know about Ubuntu, I'm using Windows hehe. Thanks in advance for your help to answer my question.

Comment: ask this question on askubuntu.com

Comment: You may also wish to sort out exactly what you are trying to ask, otherwise the Ubuntu folks may close as unclear... What are you wanting to know about access control, what are you trying to ask?